# Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) Magento 1.9.1.1 Auto Invoice After payment and change status to complete

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, paypal-express, order-status, paypal-standard

I am selling downloadable product in my website . There is payment method only Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) included . When customer checkout the order the order status is in processing . I want it Pending until i approve from admin. But it is in processing . When customer redirect to paypal and complete their payment . The status automatically change into complete and invoice auto created . i want to stop paypal to create invoice and order status in pending . i want it to change manually or creating invoic.

Anybody can help will? Suggestion also appreciable.

Thanks in advance guys .

Answer (score 1):

> Select Payment Action to "Authorize" not "Sale", then you can create
>   invoice manually and capture amount online

[image]

Comment: But i dont want to capture payment . I want i just get amount in paypal . and create manually invoice . Capture is not a good method to do this . When i captured from paypal . it will auto create the invoice . i want sale method . I appreciate your response .

Comment: You mean, when customer place the order on your Magento site with PayPal payment method. it should not create invoice. Once you capture from PayPal at that time invoice should be created in Magento?